# How to filter several lists of dicts to find a list with certain keys?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, filter

I'm new at Python and am stuck with this task.

I have a file with several lists of dicts, but only one list has all keys spelled correctly. I need to find it and print which is correct before I move to the second task, where I'm gonna use the correct list.

Example of the lists:

```
list_1 = [{'first_key': 'random value', 'second_key': 'random value', 'third_key': 'random value'}]

list_2 = [{'first_key': 'random value', 'sscond_key': 'random value', 'third_key': 'random value'}]

list_3 = [{'first_keet': 'random value', 'second_key': 'random value', 'third_key': 'random value'}]`
```

I've created a class with one method meant to for-loop through the lists of dicts, looking something like this:

```
from my_file import list_1, list_2, list_3

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, my_file, something):
        self.my_file = my_file
        self.something = something
   
    def is_key_present(self):
        for x in self.my_file:
            if self.something in x is True:
                continue
            else:
                return False 
        return
```

Now, I need to create a second method to find which list has only the right spelled keys and then print the result.

I'm fairly confident that my first method is correct, but the second one I've no clue how to set up.

I've tried something like this:

```
def check_for_keys(self): 
        check_first_key = self.is_key_present(self.something == 'first_key')
        check_second_key = self.is_key_present(self.something == 'second_key')
        check_third_key = self.is_key_present(self.something == 'third_key')


first_checker = MyClass(my_file = list_1)
first_checker.check_for_keys()
```

But when I try to call the class I get an error saying

```
first_checker = MyClass(my_file = list_1)
TypeError: MyClass.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'something'
```

I tried adding a for loop in the second method looking something like this:

```
for check_first, check_second, check_third in zip(list_1, list_2, list_3):
            if self.something in check_first or check_second or check_third is True:
                print(f'list is ok')
            else:
                print(f'list is not ok')
        print(check_email)
        print(check_model)
        print(check_purchase_date)
```

But I get the same error message as mentioned previously.

Comment: Your example input data has invalid python. They are neither lists nor dicts

Answer (score 0):

Your code has the **init**() set up with three parameters, none of which have defaults. So as a result, you need to always pass in the file and something arguments.

Comment: Please provide corrections required in the source code given the question and explain how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your imported list items should contain proper dict's:

```
list_1 = [{"first_key": "random value"}, {"second_key": "random value"}, {"third_key": "random value"}]
list_2 = [{"first_key": "random value"}, {"second_key": "random value"}, {"third_key": "random value"}]
list_3 = [{"first_key": "random value"}, {"second_key": "random value"}, {"third_key": "random value"}]
```

Think your Class is fine, you could add a print function to it as well to be used in your second method. Also suggest making your variables more human readable 'something' is not very easy to understand and follow.

```
class SearchList:
    def __init__(self, search_list, search_value):
        self.search_list = search_list
        self.search_value = search_value

    def is_key_present(self):
        return any(self.search_value in key for key in search_list.keys())

    def print_list(self):
        print(self.search_list)
```

Think the main thing for your code is how you want to handle your file of lists. As it is now you are importing each single list object. If you plan to continue doing that I would create another list to contain all your imported lists, this would make it easier to manage/loop through them. I would suggest a better method of importing your lists into a nice object/list that you can easily loop through, instead of manually coding out each list like you have.

```
from my_file import list_1, list_2, list_3
all_lists=[]
all_lists.append(list_1)
all_lists.append(list_2)
all_lists.append(list_3)
```

For your second method, it should be simple loop through your lists, use your Class to validate if the key exists and then print the list. Always try to keep your code short, simple and designed for reusability.

```
def print_valid_list(search_key):
    for single_list in all_lists:
        search = SearchList(single_list, search_key)
        if search.is_key_present:
            search.print_list
```

Answer (score -1):

You should post a sample of your file.

But then I'd something much simpler, for every line of the file, try to json decode it, and if it works the list of object is valid.

```
import json

with open('file.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
    try:
      json.decode(line)
      print('valid object', line)
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as e:
      print('invalid object')
      continue
```